# Correlated subqueries. Count Visits after Last Purchase Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pretty new to SQL and have been trying to solve this task for a while.. still no luck. I would appreciate If someone here could help me out.

I have a database with columns:
`ClientID`,
`VisitID`,
`Date`,
`PurchaseID` (array)
etc

What I'm trying to achieve is:
`ClientID`,
`Last Visit Date`,
`First Visit Date`,
`Last Purchase Date`,
`Visits Count`,
`Purchases Count`,
`Visits After Last Purchase Count`

Visits After Last Purchase Count - here I stuck.

```
SELECT 
ClientID, 
FirstVisit, 
LastVisit, 
LastPurchaseDate, 
Visits, 
Purchases, 
VisitsAfterPurchase
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    h.ClientID, 
    max(h.Date) AS LastVisit, 
    min(h.Date) AS FirstVisit, 
    count(VisitID) AS Visits
FROM s7_visits AS h 
WHERE Date > '2017-12-01'
GROUP BY h.ClientID
LIMIT 100
) 
ANY LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT 
    d.ClientID, 
    max(d.Date) AS LastPurchaseDate, 
    sum(length(d.PurchaseID)) AS Purchases, 
    sum(
    (
        SELECT count(x.VisitID)
        FROM s7_visits AS x 
        WHERE x.ClientID = d.ClientID
        HAVING x.Date >= max(d.Date)
    )) AS VisitsAfterPurchase
FROM s7_visits AS d 
WHERE (length(PurchaseID) > 0) AND (Date > '2017-12-01')
GROUP BY d.ClientID
) USING (ClientID)
```

Database I'm using is Yandex Clickhouse.
`USING` thing is absolutely normal (it is used instead of ON)

This query is giving me error:

> DB::Exception: Column Date is not under aggregate function and not in GROUP BY..

Sample Data:

```
  +----------+---------+------------+------------+
  | CliendID | VisitID |    Date    | PurchaseID |
  +----------+---------+------------+------------+
  |      123 |     136 | 01.12.2017 |            |
  |      123 |     522 | 05.12.2017 |            |
  |      123 |     883 | 08.12.2017 |            |
  |      123 |     293 | 09.12.2017 | ['345']    |
  |      123 |     278 | 12.12.2017 |            |
  |      123 |     508 | 12.12.2017 |            |
  |      123 |     562 | 15.12.2017 |            |
  |      123 |     523 | 21.12.2017 |            |
  |      456 |     736 | 29.11.2017 |            |
  |      456 |     417 | 03.12.2017 |            |
  |      456 |     950 | 04.12.2017 |            |
  |      456 |     532 | 05.12.2017 | ['346']    |
  |      456 |     880 | 09.12.2017 |            |
  |      456 |     296 | 12.12.2017 |            |
  |      456 |     614 | 15.12.2017 |            |
  +----------+---------+------------+------------+
```

And the result would be:

```
  +----------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
  | ClientID | Last Visit Date | First Visit Date | Last Purchase Date | Visits Count | Purchases Count | Visits After Last Purchase Count |
  +----------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
  |      123 |      21.12.2017 |       01.12.2017 |         09.12.2017 |            8 |               1 |                                4 |
  |      456 |      15.12.2017 |       29.11.2017 |         05.12.2017 |            7 |               1 |                                3 |
  +----------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: You have a 'table'

Comment: The error is self-explanatory.  You can't select the `Date` column because you aren't grouping by it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to `HAVING x.Date >= MAX(d.Date)`. It makes no sense to refer to the `x.Date` column because you're aggregating all the rows for `x.ClientID = d.ClientID` first, and `x.Date` will just be from a randomly selected row in that group.

If you want to select rows to be counted, you need to do that in the `WHERE` clause. So that subquery should be:

```
(
SELECT 
    d.ClientID, 
    max(d.Date) AS LastPurchaseDate, 
    sum(length(d.PurchaseID)) AS Purchases, 
    sum(
    (
        SELECT count(x.VisitID)
        FROM s7_visits AS x 
        WHERE x.ClientID = d.ClientID AND x.Date >= max(d.Date)
    )) AS VisitsAfterPurchase
FROM s7_visits AS d 
WHERE (length(PurchaseID) > 0) AND (Date > '2017-12-01')
GROUP BY d.ClientID
) USING (ClientID)
```